# Need to prevent a Windows service from starting if not licensed

Tags: c#, licensing

I am developing a service application that we plan to license and sell.  I have figured out the licensing but can't figure out the best way to prevent the service from starting, and more importantly notify the user why.  I assume I can check for the license in the onstart service event and if not licensed just call stop.  I don't want them to sit there and keep pushing start I need to notify or disable the ability to start the service if not licensed.

The onstart section of code has event logging.  A subset is here

```
     logControl.VerboseLogging = bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["verboseLogging"]);
     logControl.LogApplicationEvent("Haul Log Logger Service Starting");
     logControl.LogApplicationEvent("Verbose Logging status is " + logControl.VerboseLogging.ToString());
     //Check for license and if not licensed log error to error log and stop service.  Problem is how to notify windows service msc why it stopped.
     logControl.Connect();
     logControl.LogApplicationEvent("The server connected status is " + logControl.ConnectedStatus);
```

Any ideas on how best to do this?

Comment: You can't notify the app that tried to start the service. It could be the `services.msc` snap-in, but it could also be command prompt or even just Windows booting. You should to log to event log or some other third party route (email, log file etc.)

Comment: How do you check for license if your service is not started? Even if you do not start service, you cannot prevent folks from starting your service manually.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing The licence check is done on service start, that's the point of the question.

Comment: Why not disable the service after license check so that users cannot click on start. You can have a program that takes the licensing info and if license is valid and if service installed and service disabled then enable the service manually and then start it.

Comment: I would prepare a tiny application (.EXE) and put it into Windows Start (via Registry, or Startmenu, or TaskManager) just to see an entry in Windows Logfile OR a temp-file (in TEMP folder), created by the service. The data within Logfile or temp-file could be a kind of HASH on the current date plus a specific string (to make it against ranbow-table attacks). If the file/information is not there or if the check of its contents fails, the service hadn't started. And you make your service start and supend/stop in this tiny exe.

Comment: The service could also HASH this tiny EXE to assure that it's the original and authorized one. If the HASH fail, the service is not started.

Comment: the license check will be done during the start.  I thought there would be a way to return a code indicating why it stops immediately to the services.mmc if that is how it was started. Stopping and disabling would be more confusing I think.  I found the exit code property is service base but don't know how the code can be used. Ideally the user would press start and get a status of running or license check failed. I just can't figure out how to extend the available statuses.